# NullPointerException into RecyclerView.setLayoutManager method

Tags: android

I'm facing this bug in my app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.mRecycler' on a null object reference
```

Below I post the Logcat messages:

```
06-06 11:21:50.459 3701-3701/com.status.plug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.status.plug, PID: 3701
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.mRecycler' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerView.java:8233)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:59)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:233)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:61)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6082)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6043)
at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:22287)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6026)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5980)
at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22199)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:92)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:179)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:419)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:65)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:228)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:56)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5966)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5833)
at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:22138)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:117)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:210)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:358)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:255)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:82)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5816)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(RecyclerView.java:2803)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5795)
at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:22096)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:112)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:204)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:336)
at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDeleg
```

And the source code of the call to the RecyclerView.

```
private void setLayout() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__swipe_refresh_layout);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__recycler_view);
    mEmptyTextView = (TextView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__empty_text_view);
    Typeface fontType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), Globals.FONT_TYPE);
    mEmptyTextView.setTypeface(fontType);
}

private void setRecyclerView(CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    setSwipeLayout();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    // FIXME: Crashes always happening the line below.
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    Integer pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    List<Interest> interestsList = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests();
    Integer categoryId = interestsList.get(pageNumber).getId();

    mAdapter = new HeadlineAdapter(mActivity, mFragment, categoryId, null, mHeadlineList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Integer position = ContentManager.getInstance().getHeadlinePosition();
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
    ContentManager.getInstance().setHeadlinePosition(0);

    saveLayoutInstances();
    progressDialog.cancel();
}
```

And the XML layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_fragment_headlines_pager__swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/id_fragment_headlines_pager__recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_fragment_headlines_pager__empty_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/headlines_fragment__empty_list"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_700"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

---

Here is the source code of the class where I call "setLayout()".

```
public class HeadlinesPagerFragment extends BaseFragment {

//--------------------------------------------------
// Constants
//--------------------------------------------------

private static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
public static final Integer DELAY = 2000;

//--------------------------------------------------
// Attributes
//--------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Context.
 */

private Activity mActivity;
private Fragment mFragment;

/**
 * Recycler view.
 */

private ViewGroup mRootView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private HeadlineAdapter mAdapter;
private List<Headline> mHeadlineList = null;

/**
 * Others.
 */

private TextView mEmptyTextView;
private Dialog mBottomDialog = null;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//--------------------------------------------------
// Fragment Life Cycle
//--------------------------------------------------

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.onCreateView().");
    mActivity = getActivity();
    mFragment = this;

    Integer number = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    String color = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(number).getColor();
    ContentManager.getInstance().setCurrentThemeColor(color);
    ContentManager.getInstance().setPageNumber(number);

    mRootView = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines_pager, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setLayout();
    return mRootView;
}

/*
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.stopAudioOnResume();
    }
}
*/

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.onResume() -> At onResume().");

    // Closes dialog.
    if (mBottomDialog != null) {
        mBottomDialog.dismiss();
    }

    // Updates Headline list.
    updateHeadlineList();
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Menu
//--------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true);
    menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
    menu.getItem(2).setVisible(false);
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Layout Methods
//--------------------------------------------------

private void setLayout() {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setLayout().");

    // Sets the layout.
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__swipe_refresh_layout);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__recycler_view);
    mEmptyTextView = (TextView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.id_fragment_headlines_pager__empty_text_view);
    Typeface fontType = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), Globals.FONT_TYPE);
    mEmptyTextView.setTypeface(fontType);
}

private void setSwipeLayout() {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setSwipeLayout().");
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerChecker, DELAY);
        }
    });
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue_500, R.color.light_green_500,
            R.color.orange_500, R.color.red_500);
}

private void setRecyclerView(CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setRecyclerView().");
    setSwipeLayout();
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    // FIXME: Crashes always happening the line below.
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    Integer pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setRecyclerView() -> Page number is " + pageNumber + ".");
    List<Interest> interestsList = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests();
    Integer categoryId = interestsList.get(pageNumber).getId();
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.setRecyclerView() -> Interest id is " + categoryId + ".");

    mAdapter = new HeadlineAdapter(mActivity, mFragment, categoryId, null, mHeadlineList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Integer position = ContentManager.getInstance().getHeadlinePosition();
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
    ContentManager.getInstance().setHeadlinePosition(0);

    saveLayoutInstances();
    progressDialog.cancel();
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Headline Methods
//--------------------------------------------------

private void saveLayoutInstances() {
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setSwipeRefreshLayout(mSwipeRefreshLayout);
    }

    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    }

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setHeadlineAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    if (mEmptyTextView != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setEmptyTextView(mEmptyTextView);
    }

    if (mActivity != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setActivity(mActivity);
    }

    if (mFragment != null) {
        ContentManager.getInstance().setFragment(mFragment);
    }
}

private void getLayoutInstances() {
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout == null) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = ContentManager.getInstance().getSwipeRefreshLayout();
    }

    if (mRecyclerView == null) {
        mRecyclerView = ContentManager.getInstance().getRecyclerView();
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = ContentManager.getInstance().getHeadlineAdapter();
    }

    if (mEmptyTextView == null) {
        mEmptyTextView = ContentManager.getInstance().getEmptyTextView();
    }

    if (mActivity == null) {
        mActivity = ContentManager.getInstance().getActivity();
    }

    if (mFragment == null) {
        mFragment = ContentManager.getInstance().getFragment();
    }
}

private void updateHeadlineList() {
    // Variables.
    Integer pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> Page number is " + pageNumber + ".");
    Integer categoryId = ContentManager.getInstance().getLoggedUser().getInterests().get(pageNumber).getId();
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> Category id is " + categoryId + ".");

    // Retrofit.
    String pagination = "10,0";
    String sort = "desc";
    String filter;
    if (categoryId == 0) {
        filter = "popularity:+popular";
    } else {
        // Check filters.
        Boolean followFilter = ContentManager.getInstance().getFollowFilter();
        String append = "";
        if (followFilter) {
            append = "|following:true";
        }

        // Check place filter.
        String placeFilter = ContentManager.getInstance().getPlaceFilter();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(placeFilter)) {
            placeFilter = "|" + placeFilter;
        }
        filter = "category:" + categoryId + append + placeFilter + "|type:posts";
    }

    // Checks connection.
    if (!Utils.hasConnection(mActivity)) {
        Utils.callLostConnectionDialog(mActivity);
    } else {
        Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "--------------- HeadlinesPagerFragment.updateHeadlinesList() -> " +
            "Calling RetrofitUtils.searchMake(). Filter is '" + filter + "'.");
        ContentManager.getInstance().setCurrentSearchedCategory(categoryId);
        String[] fields = new String[] { pagination, sort, filter };
        RetrofitUtils.searchMake(mActivity, mFragment, null, fields,
            SearchMakeEnum.HEADLINES_PAGER_FRAGMENT, Utils.hourglass(mActivity));
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Callback
//--------------------------------------------------

public void checkValidHeadlineList(Boolean append, CustomProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "--------------- HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList().");
    getLayoutInstances();
    Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> " +
        "getLayoutInstances().");
    List<Post> postList = ContentManager.getInstance().getPostList();
    if (postList == null) {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mHeadlineList = RecyclerViewUtils.getHeadlineListFromPostList(postList);
        Boolean validHeadlineList = (mHeadlineList != null) && (mHeadlineList.size() > 0);
        if (validHeadlineList) {
            if (append) {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Append list.");
                mAdapter.setFilter(mHeadlineList);
                progressDialog.cancel();
            } else {
                Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Valid list.");
                mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setRecyclerView(progressDialog);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(Globals.LOG_TAG, "HeadlinesPagerFragment.checkValidHeadlineList() -> Empty list.");
            mEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------
// Handler
//--------------------------------------------------

private final Runnable mHandlerChecker = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerChecker);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Yes, they are in the same, as we can see in the above source code.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed by Google, as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=212506).